# How to close a jquery modal dialog and refresh parent page

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

i'm not able to close a jquery dialog.
Below are my code.

I have a parent page called academic.asp which will open a modal dialog by jquery plug in.

```
function openPopupDialog(location, windowTitle, heightValue, widthValue) {

    var $dialog = $('#dialogWin').load('submission.asp')
        .dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: true,
              draggable: false,
              resizable: false,
              title: windowTitle,
              width: widthValue,
              height: heightValue
         });

    $dialog.dialog('open');

    return false;
}
```

My modal window will load a page "submission.asp"

i will do some submission in my modal window by using ajaxForm as below:
paperForm = my form name

How to close the modal and refresh parent page?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

The modal is opened on the same page, so you don't have to close it. Simply reload the page:

```
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: @DmainEvent - In context of the question - on an event on the dialog, or anywhere else on the page. There is probably an even in which you want to reload the page (button click, timer, etc)